# Error in accessing zzbgl and overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, location

**error 1)**

> error: cannot access zzbgl class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

```
private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}
```

**2)**

> F:\Applications\XChange\app\src\main\java\com\example\laman\xchange\Welcome.java:
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation
>   for details.

Comment: Why don't you also explain in your code what you are trying to achieve. Simply putting the code without explaining what you want will get you least response from anyone.

Comment: How to add my full code in the question please tell

Comment: I am creating a detect my location app and created a Location request for the user to detect his location .

Comment: To add code [edit] the question and paste the code into the editor, then select it and use the button with "{}" or indent the code with four spaces.